# How to query current Directory name into a variable for batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have been researching and trying without success to get the current directory name into a variable such as `%CurrDirNam%` for creating a text file with the same folder name something the third example below which works, however when run, it overwrites the existing file and it's contents, so I modified the bottom line to check for the file's existence.
    Set DirName=%cd%
For %%A in ("%dirname%") do (
    Set Name=%%~nxA
)
IF NOT EXIST %Name%.txt Echo %Dirname% > %DirName%\%Name%.txt
Rem ---OOPS sorry I do not know how to re-format the code with CRLF and indents.  I'm new at this...

Comment: The variable I found is %cd%.  However, when trying to create the text file, an 'access denied' message is returned, even when run as administrator. the batch is Set DirName=%cd% -Followed by- Echo %Dirname% > %DirName%.txt. The use of the variable name after the redirection is what causes the message.

Comment: What is the full path to the directory you are currently in when running the command?

Comment: The drive and folder path is C:\Temp so the text file I hope to have created is temp.txt

Comment: `Echo %Dirname% > %DirName%.txt.` The first `Dirname` is not the same as the second `DirName` (look at the case of the letters)

Comment: @DavidPostill It's Windows, so not case sensitive. %Dirname% is equal to %DirName%

Comment: @Berend Indeed. I've just tested the code as is and it works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run this

```
Set DirName=%cd% 
Echo %Dirname% > %DirName%.txt
```

from **C:\Temp**, it will expand to

```
Set DirName=C:\Temp 
Echo C:\Temp > C:\Temp.txt
```

This will fail if you don't have write permissions on C:\ and would explain the *Access Denied* message you get.

If you want to create a file in C:\Temp, use something like this:

```
Set DirName=%cd% 
Echo %Dirname% > %DirName%\test.txt
```

If the name of the file must match the directory name, use this trick:

```
Set DirName=%cd%
For %%A in ("%dirname%") do (
    Set Name=%%~nxA
)
Echo %Dirname% > %DirName%\%Name%.txt
```

Comment: It should probably be noted that the user might not have a c:\temp directory and/or write access to it. If using Windows temp due, it is best to use %TEMP% variable for a place where to put temporary files

Comment: @Gnudiff No one said anything about temporary files?

Comment: that's right, I missed that you only used temp as an example

Comment: @Gnudiff I just copied that from one of the OP's comments

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on my Windows 10 system and it worked with no problem.

```
>path.txt echo %cd%
```

I ran this in a batch script while in the directory I wanted the path of.
In my case, I only wanted the path to create a URL from it
I found that by using `>url.txt echo %cd:\=/%` it also takes care of all the backslashes that needed to be forward slashes in the URL and saved me the trouble

Only step left is a little editing on the url.txt file